# MVC source code singleton pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Why does .net MVC source code ControllerBuilder use a delegate to assign the controller factory?:

```
private Func<IControllerFactory> _factoryThunk;

public void SetControllerFactory(IControllerFactory controllerFactory) {
    _factoryThunk = () => controllerFactory;
}
```

Why can't it just assign the ControllerFactory directly?, ie:

```
private IControllerFactory _factory;

public void SetControllerFactory(IControllerFactory controllerFactory) {
    _factory = controllerFactory;
}

public void SetControllerFactory(Type controllerFactoryType) {
    _factory = (IControllerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(controllerFactoryType);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that `_factoryThunk` is currently defined as a `Func<IControllerFactory>` is that it's a generic means to support both overloads:

```
void SetControllerFactory(Type);
void SetControllerFactory(IControllerFactory);
```

The implementation of the first one uses the fact that `_factoryThunk` is a `Func` by declaring that `Func` inline by using `Activator` to instantiate the `Type` lazily:

```
this._factoryThunk = delegate {
    IControllerFactory factory;
    try
    {
        factory = (IControllerFactory) Activator.CreateInstance(controllerFactoryType);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, MvcResources.ControllerBuilder_ErrorCreatingControllerFactory, new object[] { controllerFactoryType }), exception);
    }
    return factory;
};
```

Therefore, the reason the other overload looks like it has a spurious implementation is that since `_factoryThunk` is declared as a `Func`, the line you propose wouldn't have even compiled:

```
_factoryThunk = controllerFactory;
```

`_factoryThunk` is a `Func<IControllerFactory>` whereas `controllerFactory` is an `IControllerFactory` -- incompatible types.

Comment: The question is why do they need the lazy instantiation? The second method could be _factory = (IControllerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(controllerFactoryType); I've updated the question to be clearer

Comment: @JontyMC, you're absolutely right, I missed that nuance before.  After examining the source code a bit more, I believe the explanation for the design is to allow implementors of IControllerFactory to maintain state for a specific Controller that it instantiates.  i.e. The design results in a 1-1 mapping between instances of a Controller and instances of their IControllerFactory. This way, the implementation of IControllerFactory could, for example, hang on to the instance of the Controller it instantiates in a field for later use. (not sure why you would want to though)